# Express Node JS Routing Error

Tags: node.js, express

i'm new in NodeJS / Express..

so i created a simple CRUD program, but i get an error, the error is'nt in my query but in my route.

`<a href='edit/#{data.id}'>Edit Data</a>`

so if i tried to go to edit page, the url is `localhost:3000/edit/(id)`

my update form like this :

`<form action='update-data'>`

after submiting the form update, the `url` supposed to be like this `localhost:3000/update-data`

but my `url` like this : `localhost:3000/edit/update-data`

so the errors show is `update-data` routes is not defined

how to solve my prblem? thanks

Comment: The only way to really help you is if you show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your form submission to go to `http://localhost:3000/update-data`, then change your form tag from this:

```
<form action='update-data'>
```

to this:

```
<form action='/update-data'>
```

When you have no leading `/` or `http://` on the URL, it becomes page relative which means the browser uses the path of the current page URL which in your case is `localhost:3000/edit` so the browser just adds the `update-data` to that and you ended up with `localhost:3000/edit/update-data`.  Change the form tag as I recommended and the URL will now be domain relative, not page relative so the path of the current page will not be used (only the domain and protocol of the current page will be used).

Comment: @DarkCode999 - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points.